# Check if required fields are not empty when clicking button jquery (Not submit button)

Tags: jquery

Just wondering, I have a form that has steps, so you complete step1 - then step2 appears and step1 hides.

I am wondering the best way to check if the required fields for step1 have been completed when pressing my next button id : `nextbtn1`

an example of one of the fields is

```
<input type ="text" class ="form-control" required>
```

Comment: If you want to do validation on the client side and you are already using jQuery, you can use for example [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). Don't forget server side validation also. The scope of the question though is too broad for stackoverflow because there is not really specific question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you press the next button you have to perform a check an all your input fields. If one of the fields is empty you can display the information to the user and abort loading of step two.

I recommend using jquery. 
It's possible to access all input fields via jQuery via the kind of input tag, but you will also receive the inputs of the other steps.
It is a better practice to use ids and/or names for input fields.
So your input-fields will look like this (with field1,field2, etc)

```
<input type ="text" class ="form-control" id="field1" required>
```

And the check is perfromed with something like

```
fieldValue = $('#field1').val();
if( fieldValue == "" )
{
   //show info that field is empty
}
```

You just have to define a "final" check where the method checks if all fields are empty or not.

**Edit**

As Esko pointed out it would be better using a validation library for the scenario. In this case he is right, because its easier to have a library do the validation stuff instead your own implementation (except you have some special stuff - but thats not the case here).

So if you have your input fields in a form, then use the jquery validation library and use a small snippet at the end

```
$("#idOfForm").validate();
```

you have just to add some annotations and it will work:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: I really don't recommend building your own validation logic when there are so well established libraries that do it really well. Maybe change the example to use a library and create an example how to use it?